# JTable not getting populated from .txtfile

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, file-io, jtable

I have a .txt file having the following data (Note: The data in the file gets updated periodically so I dont know exactly the number of rows). My Java Application displays this data in a JTable.  Here's my txt file:

```
root         1     0  0 09:49 ?        00:00:00 init [5]  
root         2     0  0 09:49 ?        00:00:00 [kthreadd]
root         3     2  0 09:49 ?        00:00:00 [ksoftirqd/0]
root         4     2  0 09:49 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/0:0]
root         6     2  0 09:49 ?        00:00:00 [migration/0]
root         7     2  0 09:49 ?        00:00:00 [watchdog/0]
```

What I coded for it is:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelListener;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;
public class Reader {

    public Reader(){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        BufferedReader reader;
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("ProcessList.txt")));
            Map<String, Object[]> result = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object[]>();
            while(reader.ready()){
                String line = reader.readLine();
                String[] values = line.split("\\s+");
                String key = values [0] +"&"+values[4] +"&"+values[5]+"&"+values[6]+"&"+values[7];
                String uid = values [0];

                String strtime = values [4];
                String tty = values [5];
                String etime = values [6];
                String command =  values [7];
                Integer pid = 0;
                Integer pri = 0;
                Integer uti = 0;
                if (result.containsKey(key)) {
                    pid = (Integer) ((Object[]) result.get(key))[1];
                    pri = (Integer) ((Object[]) result.get(key))[2];
                    uti = (Integer) ((Object[]) result.get(key))[3];
                }
                else {}
                result.put(key, new Object[]{uid,pid,pri,uti,strtime,tty,etime,command});
            }
            ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList(result.values());
            JTable table = new JTable(new PTablemodel(arrayList));
            panel.add(new JScrollPane(table));
            reader.close();
            frame.setContentPane(panel);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.pack();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();        
        }
        catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    public static void main (String [] args){
        new Reader();
    }
    public class PTablemodel implements TableModel{

        final Class[] ColumnClass = new Class[]{String.class, Integer.class, Integer.class,Integer.class, String.class, String.class,String.class, String.class};


        final String[] columnname = new String[]{"User","PID","Priority","Utilization","TTY","StartTime","EndTime","Command"};
        List values = null;
        public PTablemodel (List values){
            this.values = values;
        }
        @Override
        public void addTableModelListener(TableModelListener l) {
        }

        @Override
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
            return ColumnClass[columnIndex];
        }

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return ColumnClass.length;
        }

        @Override
        public String getColumnName(int columnIndex) {
            return columnname[columnIndex];
        }

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            return values.size();
        } 

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            return ((Object[]) values.get(rowIndex))[columnIndex];
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void removeTableModelListener(TableModelListener l) {
        }

        @Override
        public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        }
    }
}
```

What I'm getting is not actually the error but it catches the Exception. Can anyone guide me on it? I've used "&" as tokenizer.

NOTE: Here's what the compiler says:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4
at Reader.<init>(Reader.java:30)
at Reader.main(Reader.java:65)
```

Comment: Please add the exception output to the question.

Comment: As an aside.  Who formatted that code, your dog?  Please use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Sorry for the code's indent causing you a trouble.You can see from my stupid questions how new am I to development. Thanks for bearing the code. I'll take care of the naming conventions as well as the indents next time for sure. Thanks once again :)

Answer (score 2):

This code, an SSCCE based on yours, suggests it is something in the file reading code.

[image: Reader]

#### Output

```
File - exists: true I:\projects\eclipse\Test\ProcessList.txt
Frame is visible
File - exists: false I:\projects\eclipse\Test\ProcessList1.txt
java.io.FileNotFoundException: ProcessList1.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
     ...
```

#### Code

```
package test.t100.t001;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelListener;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;
public class Reader {

    static String name = "ProcessList";

    public Reader(String name){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        BufferedReader reader;
        try {
            File f = new File(name);
            System.out.println("File - exists: " + f.exists() + " " + f.getAbsolutePath());
            reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(
                            new FileInputStream(f)));
            Map<String, Object[]> result = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object[]>();
            while(reader.ready()){
                String line = reader.readLine();
                String[] values = line.split("\\s+");
                String key = values [0] +"&"+values[4] +"&"+values[5]+"&"+values[6]+"&"+values[7];
                String uid = values [0];

                String strtime = values [4];
                String tty = values [5];
                String etime = values [6];
                String command =  values [7];
                Integer pid = 0;
                Integer pri = 0;
                Integer uti = 0;
                if (result.containsKey(key)) {
                    pid = (Integer) ((Object[]) result.get(key))[1];
                    pri = (Integer) ((Object[]) result.get(key))[2];
                    uti = (Integer) ((Object[]) result.get(key))[3];
                }
                else {}
                result.put(key, new Object[]{uid,pid,pri,uti,strtime,tty,etime,command});
            }
            ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList(result.values());
            JTable table = new JTable(new PTablemodel(arrayList));
            panel.add(new JScrollPane(table));
            reader.close();
            frame.setContentPane(panel);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.pack();
            System.out.println("Frame is visible");
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();        
        }
        catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException{
        String s = 
                "root         1     0  0 09:49 ?        00:00:00 init [5]\n" +  
                "root         2     0  0 09:49 ?        00:00:00 [kthreadd]\n" +
                "root         3     2  0 09:49 ?        00:00:00 [ksoftirqd/0]\n" +
                "root         4     2  0 09:49 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/0:0]\n" +
                "root         6     2  0 09:49 ?        00:00:00 [migration/0]\n" +
                "root         7     2  0 09:49 ?        00:00:00 [watchdog/0]\n";
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(name + ".txt");
        fos.write(s.getBytes());
        new Reader(name + ".txt");
        new Reader(name + "1.txt");
    }
    public class PTablemodel implements TableModel{

        final Class[] ColumnClass = new Class[]{String.class, Integer.class, Integer.class,Integer.class, String.class, String.class,String.class, String.class};


        final String[] columnname = new String[]{"User","PID","Priority","Utilization","TTY","StartTime","EndTime","Command"};
        List values = null;
        public PTablemodel (List values){
            this.values = values;
        }
        @Override
        public void addTableModelListener(TableModelListener l) {
        }

        @Override
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
            return ColumnClass[columnIndex];
        }

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return ColumnClass.length;
        }

        @Override
        public String getColumnName(int columnIndex) {
            return columnname[columnIndex];
        }

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            return values.size();
        } 

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            return ((Object[]) values.get(rowIndex))[columnIndex];
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void removeTableModelListener(TableModelListener l) {
        }

        @Override
        public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please learn java naming conventions and stick to them. :::-)))

Comment: @kleopatra Sorry, my eyes were still watering from the indentation.  In that state, I couldn't look that closely at the code! ;)

Comment: @AndrewThompson Sorry for posting the "Not fairly indented" code and thanks for the answer but I cant initialize the stirng with the contents of my txt file because the txt file is automatically generated by another code and what this does is that it reads whatever the contents of the txt file are, to the JTable. Can you please guide me on that? :)

Comment: Post the exception stack trace.

Comment: In fact, run the latest code (exactly as posted) and copy/paste the output as an edit to the question, along with your assessment of the problem in your code, and how to fix it.  I feel like I am spoon feeding you here.  Please lift your effort, as I don't have much patience for doing that.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting a `NullPointerException` in your `while-loop` that reads the input. You should test that `reader.readLine()` does not return `null`. If it does, it means you have reached the end of the input.

You could do something like this:

```
while((String line = reader.readLine())!=null) {
     ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting FileNotFoundException-
Make sure you are keeping the ProcessList.txt file in your project root.

[image]

If you are compiling and running them from command prompt make sure that the ProcessList.txt file is in the same location where the .class files resides.

[image]

Comment: *"make sure that the ProcessList.txt file is in the same location where the .class files resides."* It would be more optimal to figure out how to access resources by path from the root of the run-time class-path.

Comment: @AndrewThompson the file is in the same location where the .class file resides. :(

Answer (score 0):

This page seems to have been changing around alot.  Taking it as it appears as I write this, you've got a bad array index on line 30.  Specifically, you're trying to get element 4 of the array `value`, and, oddly, it does not have one.  I'm *not* a regex expert but it might be you've got an extra backslash in `line.split("\\s+")`.  If that's right, then there's something wrong with the data you're reading in.  You might start with printing out `line` (or checking it in a debugger) or just handling the actual situation.  It could just be there are one or more blank or null lines in the input which *you* don't see when you look at the file but that `readLine()`, unfortunately, does.

(I often write my own `readLine` so I can strip out unprintable characters and multiple line feeds and such--so I am not at the tender mercies of whoever wrote the file or the software they used to write it.  But here you might even want to ignore a line like "aaa", which would get through my obssesive-compulsive readLine.)